# how to find the data usage of each application in android?

Tags: android, linux

I am developing an android application where i need to capture the data usage of each application (all applications installed in the device). I can able to get the total application usage time. But i need data usage of each application. I want my application to do something like 
  [this](http://kschang.hubpages.com/slide/Data-Usage-Monitor-Apps-and-Widgets-for-Android-Phones-and-Devices/4646427)  .

Any help with some sample code will be appreciable.

Thanks

Pushpa